# How to i18n an express-graphql-App?

Tags: express, internationalization, graphql

I'm looking for an example to i18n a graphql-response: I do not want to pass in the language into every query, but I have only found very sparse documentation on how to put the language into the context to have it available for the resolve.

I'm using node and graphql-express, every hint using either this combination or any other is highly appreciated!

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial for this which might be useful: [Node.js i18n and Express.js Localization](https://lokalise.com/blog/node-js-i18n-express-js-localization/)

Answer (score 2):

as @jamuhl suggests, here is an example that uses i18next to place the selected language on the request and then uses the context to pass it down to graphql:

first set up i18next:

> ```
> const i18next = require('i18next')
> // detects language from query, cookies or Accept-Language using i18next
> i18next
>   .use(i18nMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
>   .init({
>     preload: ['en', 'de']
>    });
> app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18next));
> ```

next step is to pass it to the context-object when you set up your graphql (usually, your context-object will be more complex than that):

```
app.use('/api/v1'
        ,graphqlHTTP((req) =>{
          return {
            schema: schema.schema,
            rootValue: schema.root,
            graphiql: false,
            pretty: true,
            context: {language: req.language}
          }
        }));
```

now you can pick up the selected language from the context in your resolvers:

```
var root = {
    ... 
    yourApiCall: async (query, context, schema) => {
      let language = context.language || "en"
      ...
      return {localizedStrings: ...}
    }
```

If you don't set the context explicitly, the context is set to the request: You could derive it from there, but I still think it's better style to control your context explicitly. Please check, that this solution works for your version of graphql - the most laborous part here was to find out the proper signatures for the calls, as graphql tends to be overly clever in ommitting configuration-parameters to make it easier to be set up out of the box - most example therefore lack the signatur of query, context, schema that you need for this approach to work properly.

Comment: I used i18next express and graphql as api, and react i18next as frontend, seems it doesn't communicate each other instead of read it localhost port because the returned lang is always `en-US`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: ah, nvm, I don't need i18n on api side

Answer (score 0):

not to deep into graphql but rather sure you could solve your issue using http://i18next.com -> or more specific the express middleware https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware

Comment: yes, that is pretty much how I've done, I've only been looking for an integrated example: